# Логи через Serilog не попадают в AppInsights

Tags: c#, логирование, azure

Я создал .NET Core Console App с таким кодом:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        Log.Information("Test 1");

        Console.WriteLine("By!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Start()
    {

        TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "d7ac94ee-0a40-4691-b8ca-72e6dcb7a2c7";

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo
            .ApplicationInsights(TelemetryConfiguration.Active, TelemetryConverter.Events).CreateLogger();
    }
}
```

Соответственно установил пакет **Serilog.Sinks.AppInsights**

"d7ac94ee-0a40-4691-b8ca-72e6dcb7a2c7" -  это мой **инструментал-кей**, я взял его из Azure Portal.

При этом, в логи **абсолютно ничего не попадает** (а в моем представлении должно "Test 1" появиться).

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, где у меня ошибка?**

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Я поставил пакет https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore/ и логи стали писаться в AppInsights.